# UIColor `-colorWithPatternImage:` alpha blending problem solution. (iOS SDK 4.1)

Tags: ios, sdk, uikit, alphablending

## Solution note, not a question.

I used this code to set background as a pattern image:

```
UIImage *bg     =   SomeImage();
UIColor *bgc    =   [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bg];
[self setBackgroundColor:bgc];
[self setOpaque:NO];
```

This works, but alpha blending doesn't work. Might be a bug. How to make it work?

- Platform: `iOS SDK 4.1`

Comment: Ahh, you genius! I'm so glad you posted this Eonil. Saved me hours of head scratching and eye gouging. Might be worth mentioning: to access and modify layer properties one'll need to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code make it alpha blended on both of simulator and device.

```
UIImage *bg     =   SomeImage();
UIColor *bgc    =   [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bg];
[self setBackgroundColor:bgc];
[self setOpaque:NO];
[[self layer] setOpaque:NO];      // Added this line.
```

Comment: I did not have to set the layer opaque. It worked fine without it.

Comment: @Palimondo So, I can assume it has been patched. Thanks!